# How to remove MPAndroidChart when activity is in portrait mode?

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

I am using MPAndroidChart for one of my activities I have overridden the `onConfigurationChanged`, and when I change the orientation to landscape everything is working fine but when I switch back to portrait mode still I am seeing the chart, exactly I want to remove chart when activity switches back to portrait mode.

Here is my code

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        BarChart chart = new BarChart(this);
        if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
        {


            setContentView(chart);
            chart.animateXY(1000, 1000);
            chart.setDescription("");
            chart.setGridBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

            ArrayList<BarEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
            entries.add(new BarEntry(Float.valueOf(tvA.getText().toString()), 0));
            entries.add(new BarEntry(Float.valueOf(tvB.getText().toString()), 1));
            entries.add(new BarEntry(Float.valueOf(tvC.getText().toString()), 2));
            entries.add(new BarEntry(Float.valueOf(tvD.getText().toString()), 3));
            entries.add(new BarEntry(Float.valueOf(tvOtherPrograms.getText().toString()), 4 ));

            BarDataSet dataSet = new BarDataSet(entries, "Weekly Chart");
            dataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);

            ArrayList<String> subjectNames = new ArrayList<>();
            subjectNames.add("A");
            subjectNames.add("B");
            subjectNames.add("C");
            subjectNames.add("D");
            subjectNames.add("E");


            BarData data = new BarData(subjectNames, dataSet);
            data.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            chart.setData(data);


            XAxis xAxis = chart.getXAxis();
            xAxis.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            xAxis.setDrawLabels(true);

            YAxis yAxis =chart.getAxisLeft();
            yAxis.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);


        }

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `chart.setVisibility(View.GONE);` in `else` part?

Comment: Any reason you aren't handling this in your configuration specific layout?

Comment: @activesince93 yes but it is not working

Comment: @CoryCharlton you mean I should use from layout-land ?

Comment: @ElhamKohestani yeah that or layout-port. Define your chart or lack of a chart in the specific layout and then load the same resource with `setContentView` in `onCreate` and then check if the chart is defined or not with `findViewById` and respond accordingly.

Comment: That's weird! Its working in my case. I have used the same. The only difference is I have created `BarChart` in xml file whether you have done it programatically. And I don't this that has to do something with this stuff.